# What's the difference between JBoss ESB and JBoss HornetQ

Tags: jboss, soa

Çould anyone explain me the difference b/W Jboss ESB  and Jboss HornetQ? Do i need Jboss ESB to use JBoss HornetQ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[HornetQ](http://www.jboss.org/hornetq) is a Enterprise Grade JMS Messaging System.

[JBoss ESB](http://www.jboss.org/jbossesb) is a Enterprise Service Bus technology that can make use of a JMS Messaging System.

In the case of JBoss there is a bundled technology platform called [JBoss SOA Platform](http://www.redhat.com/products/jbossenterprisemiddleware/soa/) that includes an installation of JBoss ESB and HornetQ Messaging into JBoss EAP 5.1.

In short: HornetQ doesn't use JBoss ESB. JBoss ESB can use HornetQ but its not required.